# complex model and unique id for each item of list properties in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an asp.net mvc 3.0 and using complex model in a view as below :

```
@model StoresAndMalls.DataModel.Entities.User
........
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)
</div>

 <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Role)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserRules)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserRules,"UserRules", new { AllRules = ViewBag.AllRules})

</div>
```

Here are my models :

```
public partial class User
    {
        ......

        public virtual ICollection<UserRule> UserRules { get; set; }

        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }

 public class UserRule
    {
        .....
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RuleId")]
        public virtual Rule Rule { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

In recent projects, when I created a view with complex model, the form elements, such as Role, where prefixed with User, I mean there were like 'User.Role', but now they are not, and even though I use editor template for 'UserRules' property of User class, it also does not work as well and do not have 'User' prefix with,

here are my editor views for Role and UserRule:

```
@model IEnumerable<StoresAndMalls.DataModel.Entities.UserRule>
@{
    var allrules = (ViewData["AllRules"] as List<StoresAndMalls.DataModel.Entities.Rule>);
    int c = 0;
}
@
    foreach (var item in allrules)
    {

        @item.Description
        @Html.CheckBox(Model.Any(x => x.RuleId == item.Id))
        c++;
    <br />
    }


-----------


@model StoresAndMalls.DataModel.Entities.Role
@{
    var selecetList = (ViewData["Roles"] as List<StoresAndMalls.DataModel.Entities.Role>).
        ConvertAll(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Name, Selected = x.Id == Model.Id });
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, selecetList)


-------------
```

For 'UserRule' I tried

```
@model StoresAndMalls.DataModel.Entities.UserRule
```

But it throws :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[DataModel.Entities.UserRule]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DataModel.Entities.UserRule'.
```

Edited :

```
 public ActionResult UpdateManager(Guid id)
        {
            ViewBag.Roles = unitofwork.RoleRepository.Get();

            ViewBag.AllRules = unitofwork.UserRepository.GetByID(id).UserRules;

            var model = unitofwork.UserRepository.GetByID(id);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Can you please add the controller code for UserRole?

Comment: @nikeaa, Currently for project rush I use other approach